# What is the difference between com.microsoft.aad/adal and com.microsoft.azure/adal4j?

Tags: java, azure, adal

I am trying to turn Azure AD credentials into an OAuth2 authentication code, eventually into a token, so that I can requests to the REST resource management APIs.

Maven Central currently has two artifacts available, com.microsoft.aad/adal and com.microsoft.azure/adal4j. I have downloaded the Javadoc for both and they appear extremely similar, both using the com.microsoft.aad namespace (using adal and adal4j packages in that namespace respectively). They were both released recently and on the same day, so it doesn't appear one is deprecated. They both appear to export similar functionality, but adal4j appears to export significantly less (which makes it look more like a user-facing API, I suppose).

What's the difference between these two packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the description of both on Maven's site, I believe `com.microsoft.aad/adal` is `Azure Active Directory library for Android apps` while `com.microsoft.azure/adal4j` is `Azure Active Directory library for Java Web Apps`.

From [`http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.aad/adal/1.0.0`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.aad/adal/1.0.0):

> **Azure active directory library for Android** gives you the ability to
>   add Windows Azure Active Directory authentication to your application
>   with just a few lines of additional code. Using our ADAL SDKs you can
>   quickly and easily extend your existing application to all the
>   employees that use Windows Azure AD and Active Directory on-premises
>   using Active Directory Federation Services, including Office365
>   customers.

From [`http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/adal4j`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/adal4j):

> **Azure active directory library for Java** gives you the ability to add
>   Windows Azure Active Directory authentication to your web application
>   with just a few lines of additional code. Using our ADAL SDKs you can
>   quickly and easily extend your existing application to all the
>   employees that use Windows Azure AD and Active Directory on-premises
>   using Active Directory Federation Services, including Office365
>   customers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks -- can't believe I missed that. In my defense it feels like the library is pretty confusingly named; and it turns out they do actually share a lot of behavior...